# Setting a custom background color on Actionbar ShareActionProvider dropdownlist

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, android-actionbar, shareactionprovider

I'm trying to set a custom background color to ShareActionProvider dropdownlist, I already changed holo actionbar color using this http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/

As you can see the highlighted point at below image I could change the actionbar background color to orange but the ShareActionProvider dropdownlist background color is still gray. Does anyone have any idea how can I change it editing my theme in styles.xml?

[image]

Thank you very much for your time.

Comment: interested in this, too

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You will need to override the attribute `listPopupWindowStyle`.

From the looks of it, you're using `Theme.Holo.Light`. Add this to your base theme:

```
<style name="AppBaseTheme" parent="android:Theme.Holo.Light">
    ....
    <item name="android:listPopupWindowStyle">@style/MyListPopupWindowStyle</item>
</style>
```

Now define `MyListPopupWindowStyle` like this:

```
<style name="MyListPopupWindowStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ListPopupWindow">
    <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/list_popup_background</item>
</style>
```

Next, create the drawable `list_popup_background` and you'll be done.

**Output**:

[image]

By the way, in the screenshot above, I have used a ColorDrawable as the background. That's why, the corners are not rounded, and there's no drop shadow. For that, you'll need to create a nine-patch drawable, similar to the one that android uses. Here's what it looks like:

[image]

My ColorDrawable was defined as:

```
<drawable name="list_popup_background">#33ffffff</drawable>
```

**Some more info**:

Android itself uses a state selector drawable for ListPopupWindow's background. The selector defines two states: `state_above_anchor` & `state_below_anchor`(reachable by default):

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_above_anchor="true" android:drawable="@android:drawable/menu_popup_panel_holo_light" />
    <item android:drawable="@android:drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_holo_light" />
```

It might be a good idea for you to define something similar.

Answer (score 1):

You can tint it via **colorBackground** attribute.

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="actionBarTheme">@style/AppTheme.ActionBar</item>
</style>

<style name="AppTheme.ActionBar" parent="ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
    <item name="android:colorBackground">@color/red</item>
</style>
```